# Replace the field

Tags: php, wpallimport

I am using the following code:

```php
function my_map_field( $data ) {
    $map = array(
        'Toys for 12 years old' => '12+',
        'Toys for 4 years old' => '4+',
        'Toys for 7 years old' => '7+',
        'Toys for 9 years old' => '9+',
    );
    return isset( $map[$data] ) ? $map[$data] : null;
}
```

It replaces: Toy for 12 years old ---> 12+

I need to change the exact text mapping ('Toys for 12 years old') to if the field contains ('*12 years*')

for example:
if the field contains *12 years* write 12+; if the field contains *7 years* write 7+. If nothing is found, leave empty

Thanks

Comment: Why did you delete the previous question? You could do `(\d+)\h+years?` with `$1+` with `preg_replace` then you won't need to list every year integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Match exact word

```php
function my_map_field( $data ) {
    $map = array(
        'Toys for 12 years old' => '12+',
        'Toys for 4 years old' => '4+',
        'Toys for 7 years old' => '7+',
        'Toys for 9 years old' => '9+',
    );

    foreach ($map as $text => $number) {
        if (stripos($text, $data) !== false) {
            return $map[$text];
        }
    }
    return '';
}

echo my_map_field('7 years');// result is 7+
echo my_map_field('11 years');// result is empty
echo my_map_field('12 years');// result is 12+
```

##### Match any number with year[s]

```php
function my_map_field( $data ) {
    $map = array(
        'Toys for 12 years old' => '12+',
        'Toys for 4 years old' => '4+',
        'Toys for 7 years old' => '7+',
        'Toys for 9 years old' => '9+',
    );

    preg_match('/(\d+)\s*year[s]?/i', $data, $matches);
    $matchNumber = ($matches[1] ?? '');

    foreach ($map as $text => $number) {
        if (stripos($text, $matchNumber) !== false) {
            return $map[$text];
        }
    }
    return '';
}

echo my_map_field('buy toys for 12 years old');// get 12+
echo my_map_field('used toys for 12 years old');// get 12+
echo my_map_field('buy toys for 15 years old');// get empty.
```

Comment: I tried it and it works very well. Thank you. I have an additional question. What if the text 'Toys for 12 years old' is different. For example 'buy toys for 12 years old', 'used toys for 12 years old'. But at the end, it always contains '12 years'.

Comment: @MichalKovalčík Updated my answer to support any string that contains number and follow with year(s).

Comment: do I need to have any possible combination for 'buy toys for 12 years old' (by echo my_map_field). Because I do not know all possible sentences, I know only that the '12 years' is available. It is more like search '*12 years*' ... return 12+, search '*15 years*' ... return 15+

Comment: You can copy that code to try with any sentence you want. Search 15 years return empty if you don't have anything about that in `$map` array. It doesn't return 15+ but empty string.

Comment: @MichalKovalčík In the `preg_match()`, this pattern `/(\d+)\s*year[s]?/i` means match any number (`(\d+)`) and maybe follow with 0 space or more (`\s*`) and follow with the word _year_ (`year`) with or without s (`[s]?`). The `i` at the end means case in-sensitive. It can be 12 YEAR or 12 YeaRS.

Comment: If you would like to search some thing like _5 years_ and expect return 5+ then you could use the code in @user3783243 comment. Because this looks like it is going off topic. It is different from your main question.

Comment: ok, I will try it. thank you